# How can I get the user's email address from Facebook login with yesod-auth-fb?

Tags: facebook, haskell, yesod

I am a newbie to Haskell, Yesod, and the Facebook developer API; nevertheless I'm trying to write a web app using these technologies.  The first feature I am trying to implement is that users must be able to log in to my web app using their Facebook login, and I need to get both a unique user ID and their email address.

Here's my code so far; this is pretty much a duplicate of the code you can find on http://www.yesodweb.com/book/authentication-and-authorization.  The only thing I changed was to switch from BrowserID to Facebook Login auth, requesting the "email" permission.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
import           Data.Default           (def)
import           Data.Text
import           Network.HTTP.Conduit   (Manager, newManager)
import qualified Facebook as FB
import           Yesod
import           Yesod.Auth
import           Yesod.Facebook (YesodFacebook(..))
import           Yesod.Auth.Facebook.ServerSide

data App = App
    { httpManager :: Manager
    }

mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
/auth AuthR Auth getAuth
|]

instance Yesod App where
    approot = ApprootStatic "<my server url>"

instance YesodAuth App where
    type AuthId App = Text
    getAuthId = return . Just . credsIdent

    loginDest _ = HomeR
    logoutDest _ = HomeR

    authPlugins _ =
        [ authFacebook ["email"]
        ]

    authHttpManager = httpManager

    maybeAuthId = lookupSession "_ID"

instance YesodFacebook App where
    fbCredentials _ = FB.Credentials "<my app>" "<my app id>" "<my secret>"
    fbHttpManager = httpManager

instance RenderMessage App FormMessage where
    renderMessage _ _ = defaultFormMessage

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    maid <- maybeAuthId
    defaultLayout
        [whamlet|
            <p>Your current auth ID: #{show maid}
            $maybe _ <- maid
                <p>
                    <a href=@{AuthR LogoutR}>Logout
            $nothing
                <p>
                    <a href=@{AuthR LoginR}>Go to the login page

        |]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    man <- newManager def
    warpEnv $ App man
```

When I run this, it works - I can log in and out, the facebook login page states that I'm granting access to my email address, and I get the user ID back properly.  So far, so good.

However I can't figure out how to actually get the user's email address once I'm logged in.

Can someone provide some guidance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with Facebook API before, and, as far as I can remember, all you're getting back is an access token to use for sending your Facebook API requests. What you probably should do to get an e-mail address of a logged-in user is to send an HTTP request (or use a Facebook API library) for fetching user information, with the appropriate `fields` argument. More details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user).